# data not shown when useing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am using a view pager, with actionbar.

this action bar contains 3 tabs.

one of them is `players`, i called it like this:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new TeamInformation();
            case 1:
                return new TeamPlayers();
            default:
                return new TeamInformation();
            }
        }
```

and the `TeamPlayers` class is :

```
public class TeamPlayers extends Fragment {

    private ListView lv_players;
    private TeamPlayersAdapter adapter;
    private List<Player> players = new LinkedList<Player>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.team_players, container, false);
        lv_players = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_players);
        adapter = new TeamPlayersAdapter(this.getActivity(), players);
        lv_players.setAdapter(adapter);
        new getTeamPlayers().execute(1);
        return v;
    }
```

when i call this screen, i got nothing, i mean not any data show, although, if you notice i call the `getTeamPlayers` which is:

```
private class getTeamPlayers extends
            AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, List<Player>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Player> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            List<Player> players = new LinkedList<Player>();
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setID(1);
            player.setEn_name("Totti");
            players.add(player);
            player = new Player();
            player.setID(2);
            player.setEn_name("De Rossi");
            players.add(player);
            return players;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Player> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            players = new LinkedList<Player>();
            players.addAll(result);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

see i put data in it. i make a log to check if the application called the `onCreateView` and i can see the log.

#### help appreciated

Comment: Try to remove `super.onPostExecute(result);` from `onPostExecute`. Is that code reached?

Comment: @Szymon still the same, nothing appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set adapter when the list is loaded means on postExecute

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Player> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    players = new LinkedList<Player>();
    players.addAll(result);
    adapter = new TeamPlayersAdapter(this.getActivity(), players);
    lv_players.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I will try your solution now, but absolutely it won't work. the listview has already taken the adapter, and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is enough, i have done that like millions of time. however, let me try your solution now and i will tell you the result

Comment: OH DEAR GOT, it works, thank you very much. why is that ? what was the wrong with my code? also, my code was working when using activity not frament

Answer (score 0):

this may help you... no need to set the Adapter to `ListView` multiple times...

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Player> result) {
        if(result != null) {
           players.clear();
           players.addAll(result);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```